# Performance on new technical id generation for all elements

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Is there any better option to "replace" existing _id value for all elements in collection rather than remove and insert document again without _id (which will be auto generated by mongo) ?

Current solution is very slow and seems to be inefficient (I'm able to process few documents per second)

```
        mongoTemplate.getCollection(collectionName).find(filter)
        .forEach((Document document) -> {
            mongoTemplate.remove(document, collectionName);
            Object oldId = document.remove(ID);
            preAction.accept(document);
            Document newDocument = mongoTemplate.insert(document, collectionName);
            postAction.accept(new IdMigrationData(oldId, newDocument.get(ID)));
        });
```

Update _id on MongoDB document with $set operation is forbidden.

I was trying parallel processing using

```
StreamSupport.stream(mongoTemplate.getCollection(collectionName).find(filter).spliterator(), true)
```

It's a little bit faster but NPE if thrown on `.forEach(...)` execution after some time.

Comment: You going in right direction with parallel approach. Show us error you got.

Comment: @talex Error was thrown from Mongock (timeout for long-running operations). But still this approach (with parallel processing) is too slow.

Comment: It is inevitably slow, because it requires reindexing. One thing I can suggest is to create another collection and fill then drop first when you done instead of removing entities one by one.